# Is the Client ID in Google Measurment Protocol mandatory when User ID is used?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

The [Google Measurement Protocol documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) claims that the `cid` is optional if `uid` is used:

> This field is required if User ID (uid) is not specified in the request

So I make the following requests to measurement protocol:

```
GET https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=<MY_TID>&aip=1&uid=<USER_ID>&ec=Foo&ea=Bar&el=Baz
```

But they do not get recorded in Google Analytics.

I make other requests where I specify *both* `uid` and `cid` and they work perfectly. Is there something I am missing? Elsewhere I have read that `cid` is actually mandatory.

### EDIT: SOLUTION

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62387535/694195) is a correct answer to my question, so accepted. But I wanted to add that in addition to the fact that these hits were never going to show up in the Main View (only the User ID view), I had neglected to set `t=event` in my request (necessary for `ec`, `ea` and `el`). The debug endpoint didn't help diagnosing this I just stared at it (and the docs) for long enough to see it.

Comment: Did you check the debug endpoint? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits Did you check the real time reports? is your hit shown there?

Comment: @DaImTo I did check the debug endpoint, but unfortuntely it didn't help me with my root problem (I will edit question with my solution). It was not showing up in the realtime report.

Comment: the debug endpoint should have told you that the call was invalid.

Comment: @DalmTo yeah, it should have :/ Unfortunately it didn't say something useful like "ec only valid with event type 'event'", the debug endpoint said it was valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mandatory because if you don't send it but you send only uid, the hit will be appear only in USER-ID view.

Comment: Ok yes I can confirm this behaviour